# "The property gtin12 is not recognized by Google for an object of type Text"

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I read some information from https://schema.org/identifier and https://schema.org/Text.

```html
<div itemprop="identifier" itemtype="http://schema.org/Text" itemscope>
  <meta itemprop="gtin12" content="{$product.upc}" />
</div>
```

Here in https://schema.org/Text property `gtin12` is present, but I got this error in Google Schema tester:

> The property `gtin12` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Text`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Text`](https://schema.org/Text) is a data type. Data types aren’t supposed to be used as types like that.

If you want to add [`gtin12`](https://schema.org/gtin12) to a `Product`, you don’t need to specify [`identifier`](https://schema.org/identifier) (because `gtin12` is a sub-property of `identifier`) nor `Text` (in Microdata, the `content` value is by definition a text value).

```html
<!-- if the gtin12 should not be visible on the page -->
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <meta itemprop="gtin12" content="{$product.upc}" />
</article>
```

```html
<!-- if the gtin12 should be visible on the page -->
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <p itemprop="gtin12">{$product.upc}</p>
</article>
```